# given the characteristic function $e^{-\sqrt{|t|}}$ , how to calculate the cumulative distribution function？

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is $\phi(t)=e^{-\sqrt{|t|}}$, we now want to calculate the cumulative distribution function of $X$. It seems that it's hard to do the integration through inverse fourier transform $\dots$

Answer (score 1):

This is a symmetric stable distribution with index $\frac 1 2$. There is no simple expression for the density function but properties of this distribution have been studied well. There is also a series representation of the density function.

Comment: Thanks very much! So...where can I find more details or properties of it? Does it have a special name or something?

Comment: For each $\alpha \in (0,2]$ there are what are called stable distributions with index $\alpha $. You can visit my site www.statmathbc.wordpress.com and look at my notes on Infinitely Divisible Distributions for more information.